# Reading newline from previous input when reading from keyboard with scanf()

Tags: c, string, char

This was supposed to be very simple, but I'm having trouble to read successive inputs from the keyboard.

Here's the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[200];
    char character;
    printf ("write something: ");
    scanf ("%s", string);
    printf ("%s", string);
    printf ("\nwrite a character: ");
    scanf ("%c", &character);
    printf ("\nCharacter %c  Correspondent number: %d\n", character, character);

    return 0;
}
```

**What is happening**

When I enter a string (e.g.: computer), the program reads the newline (`'\n'`) and puts it in `character`. Here is how the display looks like:

```
 write something: computer
 computer
 Character:
    Correspondent number: 10
```

Moreover, the program does not work for strings with more than one word.
How could I overcome these problems?

Comment: `scanf` is insecure, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @John In this use case, yes, but not in general!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Scanf works wierd while taking a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547850/why-scanf-works-wierd-while-taking-a-character)

Comment: @ericbn you're right - the question you posted is essentially similar to mine. However, hackks and alexis added relevant information which might be useful for other users

Comment: @ElCid, sure! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf ("%s", string);'  the user could overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and leading to a seg fault event.  suggest: 'scanf ("%199s", string);'

Answer (score 9):

First `scanf` read the entered string and left behind `\n` in the input buffer. Next call to `scanf` read that `\n` and store it to `character`.
Try this

```
scanf (" %c", &characte);   
     // ^A space before %c in scanf can skip any number of white space characters.
```

Program will not work for strings more than one character because `scanf` stops reading once find a white space character. You can use `fgets` instead

```
 fgets(string, 200, stdin);
```

Comment: OP's use of `printf()` is correct.  Variadic arguments like `char character` are promoted using the usual proportion to `int` (or rarely `unsigned`) so the cast `int` is not needed.  `printf ("%c %d",...` takes two `int` arguments so OP is using the correct  specifier.  "d,i The `int` argument is converted ..." "c If no l length modifier is present, the `int` argument... "  C11 §7.21.6.1 8

Comment: I agree with using fgets() rather than scanf() to read a line of text.  However, the second input is expected to input the 'newline' and 'newline' is white space, so the suggested: scanf (" c", &character); will not work as scanf will skip over the new line.  Maybe that is what is wanted, the question was unclear on that detail.

Comment: @user3629249; It is always safe to use `" %c"` in `scanf`. What if user will press Enter/Return twice?

Answer (score 5):

OP's first problem is typically solved by prepending a space to the format.  This will consume white-space including the previous line's `'\n'`.

```
// scanf("%c", &character);
scanf(" %c", &character);
```

---

> Moreover, the program does not work for strings with more than one word. How could I overcome these problems?

For the the 2nd issue, let us go for a more precise understanding of "string" and what `"%s"` does.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. 7.1.1 1

OP is not entering a string even though "I enter a string (e.g.: computer)," is reported.  OP is entering a line of text.  8 characters "computer" followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  There is no "null character" here.  Instead 9 `char` `"computer\n"`.

`"%s"` in `scanf("%s", string);` does 3 things:

1) Scan, but not save any leading white-space.

2) Scan and save into `string` any number of non-white-space.

3) Stop scanning when white-space or EOF reached.  That `char` is but back into `stdin`.  A `'\0'` is appended to `string` making that `char` array a C *string*.

To read a line including spaces, do not use  `scanf("%s",...`.  Consider `fgets()`.

```
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);
// remove potential trailing \r\n as needed
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0;
```

Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is a problem as calls like `scanf("%s", string); fgets(...)` leave the `'\n'` in `stdin` for `fgets()` to read as a line consisting of only `"\n"`.  Recommend instead to read *all* user input using `fgets()` (or `getline()` on *nix system).  *Then* parse the line read.

```
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);
scanf(string, "%c", &character);
```

---

If code *must* user `scanf()` to read user input including spaces:

```
scanf("%*[\n]"); // read any number of \n and not save.
// Read up to 199 `char`, none of which are \n
if (scanf("%199[^\n]", string) != 1) Handle_EOF();
```

---

Lastly, code should employ error checking and input width limitations.  Test the return values of all input functions.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the correct behavior of the functions you call:

- scanf will read *one* word from the input, and leave the input pointer immediately after the word it reads. If you type `computer<RETURN>`, the next character to be read is the newline.
- To read a whole line, including the final newline, use `fgets`. Read the documentation carefully: `fgets` returns a string that includes the final newline it read. (`gets`, which shouldn't be used anyway for a number of reasons, reads and discards the final newline.)

I should add that while `scanf` has its uses, using it interactively leads to *very* confusing behavior, as I think you discovered. Even in cases where you want to read word by word, use another method if the intended use is interactive.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `%*c`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[200];
    char character;
    printf ("write something: ");
    scanf ("%s%*c", string);
    printf ("%s", string);
    printf ("\nwrite a character: ");
    scanf ("%c%*c", &character);
    printf ("\nCharacter %c  Correspondent number: %d\n", character, character);

    return 0;
}
```

`%*c` will accept and ignore the newline or any white-spaces

Comment: Note: `%*c` will accept and ignore any following `char` which is often the newline, but could be any white-space like `' '`.

Comment: @ chux, Yes, that's right. I will add your note to my answer precisely.

Comment: This has a buffer overflow; you need to limit the input

Answer (score 0):

You cal also put `getchar()` after the `scanf` line. It will do the job :)

Answer (score -2):

The streams need to be flushed. When performing successive inputs, the standard input stream, stdin, buffers every key press on the keyboard. So, when you typed "computer" and pressed the enter key, the input stream absorbed the linefeed too, even though only the string "computer" was assigned to `string`. Hence when you scanned for a character later, the already loaded new line character was the one scanned and assigned to `character`.

Also the stdout streams need to be flushed. Consider this:

```
...
printf("foo");
while(1)
{}
...
```

If one tries to execute something like this then nothing is displayed on the console. The system buffered the `stdout` stream, the standard output stream, unaware of the fact it would be encounter an infinite loop next and once that happens, it never gets a chance to unload the stream to the console.

Apparently, in a similar manner whenever `scanf` blocks the program and waits on `stdin`, the standard input stream, it affects the other streams that are buffering. Anyway, whatsoever may be the case it's best to flush the streams properly if things start jumbling up.

The following modifications to your code seem to produce the desired output

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char string[200];
char character;

printf ("write something: ");

fflush(stdout);

scanf ("%s", string);

fflush(stdin);

printf ("%s", string);
printf ("\nwrite a character: ");

fflush(stdout);

scanf ("%c", &character);
printf ("\nCharacter %c  Correspondent number: %d\n", character, character);

return 0;
}
```

*Output*:
write something: computer
computer
write a character: a

Character a  Correspondent number: 97

Comment: Your code has a buffer overflow, and `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M any evidence to back up the fact that fflush produces undefined behaviour ! And I didn't quite get the buffer overflow part can you please rephrase/explain. Thanks.

Comment: If they type 200 letters then you overflow `string`. For `fflush` see section 7.21.5.2/2 of the current C standard, "If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined".  `stdin` is not an output or update stream.

Comment: @M.M As far as buffer overflow goes, that's not the point I was trying to make. Obviously an array would overflow if you try storing data beyond its capacity. I was neither addressing that issue nor trying to accommodate for that in my code.

Comment: @M.M  And yes the specification says so, but still `fflush` is behaving entirely as one would predict and as is  supposed to even with an input stream hence I think it'd be safe to assume that `stdin` can be flushed in this manner without any repercussions unless you've a counter example where flushing stdin between successive inputs results in undefined behaviour.  Also I amn't quite aware of the term update stream, can you please tell me what exactly does it mean, and what's exactly the difference between an input stream and an update stream. Thanks.

Comment: fflush isn't behaving as I would predict and it is not supposed to do some particular thing for an input stream. You are mistakenly assuming that behaviour you observed on one compiler is standard behaviour.  "update stream" means one that can be used for reading and writing (opened with `+` flag)

Comment: @M.M I understand what you are trying to point out. Can you please give me a compiler version and a corresponding environment and a particular program where `fflush` goes haywire. It's just that I want to see it for myself how exactly things go in that case. Also, you say "it isn't supposed to do some particular things for an input stream...", what all is it not supposed to do that it's doing here, can you please be more specific ? All that's visible in the foreground is that it flushed the extra characters present in the stream which I feel is acceptable, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: See [what is undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). *There is no defined behaviour for fflush on an input stream*. You still do not seem to understand this.  You could google "fflush stdin does not work" for examples of people who had similar misgivings to yourself, and see what systems they were on.

Comment: Got it! Thanks ! Peace out.