# why does fscanf read garbage values

Tags: c

I have a simple file as below:

```
1
3
a 7
```

and when I run the code below, I get some unexpected result. I initially try to read the first two integers and then read the character `a` and number `7`. There is no white space after the number `1` or `3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int  num1, num2, num3;
    char t;

    fscanf(f, "%d",&num1);
    fscanf(f, "%d",&num2);


    fscanf(f, "%c %d", &t, &num3);
    printf("%c %d\n", t, num3);
}
```

EDIT:

Input is the file with the content:

```
    1
    3
    a 7
```

and the output is a new line and some garbage. Expected output should be `a 7`

EDIT 2: it reads correctly 1 and 3. Then trying to read a single character `a` if fails

Comment: check the return value of fscanf

Comment: Please clarify your problem statement: **exact** input, **exact** expected output, **exact** actual output along with results of each `scanf`. And, as @SouravGhosh already stated: **always** verify the results of `scanf`. Use a debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading newline from previous input when reading from keyboard with scanf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905009/reading-newline-from-previous-input-when-reading-from-keyboard-with-scanf)

Comment: Verifying the return value of `scanf` is fine and dandy, but the return value won't tell you *why* it has failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loooks at what happens when you run this:

```
fscanf(f, "%d",&num1);
```

skips whitespace (of which there is none), then reads an integer (1)

```
fscanf(f, "%d",&num2);
```

skips whitespace (the newline at the end of the first line) then reads an integer (3)

```
fscanf(f, "%c %d", &t, &num3);
```

reads the next caharcter from the input (a newline), then skips whitespace (none) and tries to read an integer.  The next input character is '`a`', so this fails, and the `fscanf` call returns 1 without writing anything into num3.

So the problem you are having is that due to the fact that `%c` does *NOT* skip whitespace, you are reading the whitespace (newline) instead of the character you expect.  The most obvious solution is to add a space () to the format to skip whitespace:

```
fscanf(f, " %c%d", &t, &num3);
```

Note that I've also removed the space before `%d`, as it is redundant (`%d` always skips whitespace).

In addition, it is always a good idea to check the return value of `fscanf` to make sure it is reading the number of input items you expect.