# Escape scanf within a while loop

Tags: c, scanf

I have this sheet of code:

```
listCh remplir(){
    char rep;
    listCh l,aux,p;
    printf("1-veuillez entrer un element?(n pour quitter)\n");
    scanf("%c",&rep);
    if(rep=='n')
        l=NULL;
    else{
        l=malloc(sizeof(listCh));
        printf("2-Donnez la valeur d element!\n");
        scanf("%d",&l->valeur);
        p=l;
    }
    while(rep!='n'){
        printf("voulez-vous ajouter un nouveau element de la list? (n pour quitter)\n");
        scanf("%c",&rep);
        if(rep!='n'){
            aux=malloc(sizeof(listCh));
            printf("Donnez la valeur d element!\n");
            scanf("%d",aux->valeur);
            p->suiv=aux;
            p=aux;
        }
        else{
            p->suiv=NULL;
        }

    }
    return l;
}
```

There is no error while executing !
But, the problem is that my program escapes the first "scanf" function in the "while" loop.

I didn't find an explanation for this.

I need some help please.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading newline from previous input when reading from keyboard with scanf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905009/reading-newline-from-previous-input-when-reading-from-keyboard-with-scanf)

Comment: Really no error? `listCh l; l=malloc(sizeof(listCh));` seems strange.

Comment: 1)  `scanf("%d",&(aux->valeur));`  (add &)  Check your compiler setting.  A good compiler would warn about this.  2) `scanf("%c",&rep);` --> `scanf(" %c",&rep);`  (add space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember to put a space before `%c` when `scanf()` a character variable. A bit unusual, but that's how to skip all the buffered spaces in the input stream before you can get the real character.

`scanf("%c",&rep);` should be `scanf(" %c",&rep);`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably reading your enter from your first `scanf`.
Try putting a `getchar()` before your scanf on the loop